# Distributing C# Class Library for UWP

Tags: c#, c++, uwp

I have core functionality written in c++. 
To use this from UWP, I made dynamic library and chained like this: **[c++ native dll]** - **[c++/cx windows runtime component]** - **[UWP c# class library]**.

c# dll provides API for UWP and c++/cx is used just for interoperability between c++ and c#.


My test UWP app works fine and now I want to distribute my dlls.

Is there a way to distribute my dlls in **all-in-one** structure? (like aar)

If possible, I want to make one library for UWP encompassing above **[c++ native dll]** - **[c++/cx windows runtime component]** - **[UWP c# class library]**.


Any hint or resource would be grateful

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nuget should work for this. By the way, WinRT libraries can be used from C# projects directly, perhaps C# project in this chain is not needed.

Comment: @OlegMikhailov I will try Nuget package. Thank you for advise. I'm not familiar with C++/CX so I used C# project for easy of use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to distribute my dlls in all-in-one structure? (like aar)

You may refer .NetStandard library, and mix them in one [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) library. And if you want this library could run in the multiple platform, you need to refer Xamarin Forms class library structure, for more detail please refer this [blog](https://www.glennwatson.net/posts/first-post).